# Using sed to find a range of lines that match two dates

Tags: linux, bash, search, sed

excuse me for my English, I used google translator

I'm trying to create a script in bash to find in a file a certain range of lines that coincide with an initial and final time passed by parameters.

I make the call to the program as follows

```
bash script_name.sh filename.txt epoch1 epoch2
```

the script is incomplete and is the following

```
#!/bin/bash
#--getting first and last ocurrency of sessionA
f_line=$(grep -n -m 1  SessionA "$1")
e_line=$(grep -n SessionA "$1" | tail -n1)
#-getting line number by ocurrency
n_line1=$(echo "${f_line}"|awk -F ':' '{print $1}')
n_line2=$(echo "${e_line}"|awk -F ':' '{print $1}')
#--getting first and last timestamp in file for ocurrency
epoch1=$(echo "${f_line}"|awk -F '|' '{print $1}'|awk -F ' ' '{print $14}')
epoch2=$(echo "${e_line}"|awk -F '|' '{print $1}'|awk -F ' ' '{print $14}')

cont=1
#--Comparing input epoch and in file epoch to validate file to search
if [ $2 -ge $epoch1 ] && [ $3 -le $epoch2 ]
then
#--since here i want search for a timestamp near or equals to first epoch parameter and last
#--this will be a lineal search first from head and after from tail() and i like say to sed that
#--print lines in range and only SessionA word in line 
sed -n ${n_line1},${n_line2}p,/SessionA/p "$1" | tail -n1 | while read -r a_line ; do
cont=$((cont+1))
 epoch_c=$(echo "${a_line}"|awk -F '|' '{print $1}'|awk -F ' ' '{print $14}')
#echo $epoch_c $2

if ! [ $epoch_c -le $2 ]
then
n_linec=$cont
echo $a_line
fi
done
fi
```

A file has thousands of the following lines, they are cgn traces:

```
Jan  1 06:22:25 11.11.20.2  1 <2020> <Jan> <01> <06:22:26> 11.11.20.2 _nohostname - <NAT444>:<SessionW> 1577877723|1577877746|10.247.32.280|152.207.177.36|1055|172.217.3.130|443|6
Jan  1 06:22:25 11.11.20.2  1 <2020> <Jan> <01> <06:22:26> 11.11.20.2 _nohostname - <NAT444>:<SessionW> 1577877739|1577877746|10.242.17.186|152.206.221.168|1099|160.44.199.23|443|6
Jan  1 06:22:25 11.11.20.2  1 <2020> <Jan> <01> <06:22:26> 11.11.20.2 _nohostname - <NAT444>:<SessionW> 1577877723|1577877746|10.247.32.28|152.207.177.36|1052|34.204.165.176|443|6
Jan  1 06:22:25 11.11.20.2  1 <2020> <Jan> <01> <06:22:26> 11.11.20.2 _nohostname - <NAT444>:<SessionW> 1577877738|1577877746|10.247.16.24|152.207.177.202|1157|172.217.2.142|443|6
Jan  1 06:22:25 11.11.20.2  1 <2020> <Jan> <01> <06:22:26> 11.11.20.2 _nohostname - <NAT444>:<SessionW> 1577877739|1577877746|10.247.16.24|152.207.177.202|1158|190.92.112.12|443|6
Jan  1 06:22:25 11.11.20.2  1 <2020> <Jan> <01> <06:22:26> 11.11.20.2 _nohostname - <NAT444>:<SessionW> 1577877730|1577877746|10.247.32.24|152.207.177.36|1107|104.154.126.1|80|6
Jan  1 06:22:25 11.11.20.2  1 <2020> <Jan> <01> <06:22:26> 11.11.20.2 _nohostname - <NAT444>:<SessionA> 1577877746|-|10.242.16.132|152.206.221.78|1167|157.185.128.201|80|6
Jan  1 06:22:25 11.11.20.2  1 <2020> <Jan> <01> <06:22:26> 11.11.20.2 _nohostname - <NAT444>:<SessionA> 1577877746|-|10.242.16.132|152.206.221.78|1168|8.37.236.225|80|6
Jan  1 06:22:26 11.11.20.2  1 <2020> <Jan> <01> <06:22:26> 11.11.20.2 _nohostname - <NAT444>:<SessionA> 1577877746|-|10.242.16.132|152.206.221.78|1169|8.37.236.225|80|6
Jan  1 06:22:26 11.11.20.2  1 <2020> <Jan> <01> <06:22:26> 11.11.20.2 _nohostname - <NAT444>:<SessionA> 1577877746|-|10.242.16.132|152.206.221.78|1170|8.37.236.225|80|6
```

The traces with sessionA are the ones that interest me and also the ones ordered by times, they are the ones that I would use to know the beginning and end of the range, knowing the line numbers I would use sed to return all the range found

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, and welcome on SO. What you want to do is unclear. Could you give us a little input file example, how you would call your program, what you want as output and what you get actually. (see [MCVE])

Comment: I want get all lines beetwen some near or equeal epoch in range that make both epoch input , but i stuck in sed parameter that gave me a range of line but have sessionW word in lines an just want sessionA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want, try something like this -

```
awk -F'[|: ]' -v lo="$2" -v hi="$3" '/SessionA/{ if ( $21 >= lo && $22 <= hi ) { print $0 } }' "$1"
```

Comment: Perfect thank for the answer, awk is strongest in few line excellent work, thanks

Comment: how you filter by a specified ip, say that i want line that get a ip in same awk command i guess that i put next SessionA filter but dont work for me, the ip i pass in parameter $4 , how make this possible, this is my idea... '/SessionA/$4{ if (...

Comment: i find the solution from Paul answer is follow``` awk -F'[|: ]' -v lo="$2" -v hi="$3" -v ip="$4" '/SessionA/{ if ( $21 >= lo && $21 <= hi && ($23 == ip || $24 == ip || $26 == ip)) { print $0 } }' "$1"```

Comment: i find the solution from Paul answer is follow``` awk -F'[|: ]' -v lo="$2" -v hi="$3" -v ip="$4" '/SessionA/{ if ( $21 >= lo && $21 <= hi && ($23 == ip || $24 == ip || $26 == ip)) { print $0 } }' "$1"```

Comment: You might also try `awk -F'[|: ]' -v lo="$2" -v hi="$3" -v ip="$4" '/SessionA/{ if ( $0 ~ ip && $21 >= lo && $21 <= hi ) { print $0 } }' "$1"`